# How to resolve Ninja c++ build and execution

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project based on CMake that uses Ninja. It's been build and ran using eclipse for C/C++. My current machine is a Mac OS.
The file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Server {
private:
    static int load;
public:
    static int compute(long long A, long long B) {
        load += 1;
        if(A < 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("A is negative");
        }
        vector<int> v(A, 0);
        int real = -1, cmplx = sqrt(-1);
        if(B == 0) throw 0;
        real = (A/B)*real;
        int ans = v.at(B);
        return real + A - B*ans;
    }
    static int getLoad() {
        return load;
    }
};
int Server::load = 0;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--) {
        long long A, B;
        cin >> A >> B;

        /* Enter your code here. */
                try{
            cout << Server::compute(A, B) << endl;
        } catch(invalid_argument e){
            cout << "Exception: A is negative" << endl;
        } catch(bad_alloc &e){
            cout << "Not enough memory" << endl;
        } catch(exception &e){
            cout << "Exception: ";
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        } catch(...){
            cout << "Other Exception" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << Server::getLoad() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build info:

```
cmake --build . -- -v
[1/2] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/deleteme.dir/deleteme.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/deleteme.dir/deleteme.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/deleteme.dir/deleteme.cpp.o -c ../../deleteme.cpp
[2/2] : && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/deleteme.dir/deleteme.cpp.o  -o deleteme   && :
Build complete (0 errors, 0 warnings):
```

When I run:

```
Building in: 
cmake --build . -- -v
ninja: no work to do.
Build complete (0 errors, 0 warnings):
```

It does not give me the chance to input the values. It just skips everything and finishes execution. If I put a cout right at the beginning, then the program works as expected.

Why is this happening?

Ps: The project complete path was removed from here for safety reasons. And yes, my project was created with the name 'deleteme'.

Pss: I took this snippet from HackerRank for studing purposes, so It should be fine. I've only added the try/catch and method call.

Comment: My impression is that this was caused by the '--build' argument for cmake. Could you try to put -G Ninja on the cmake line: cmake --build . -- -v -GNinja.
Or what I would normally do is out of source build:
1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -GNinja ..
4. ninja

Comment: Tangent, P.S. stands for Post Script. Additional post scripts would add 'P's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured It out how to solve this. I don't know what have caused It. It looks like ninja is not need if you have properly configured your environment variables, related to your compiler, inside Eclipse.

After doing that, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing *building* your program with *running* your program.

When you run the command `cmake --build . -- -v`, cmake will **build** your project. That means it will launch the appropriate tools to **compile and link** your program, which will produce an executable called `deleteme` somewhere in your build directory.
The subsequent invocation of the same command correctly reports that no work needs to be done (since you presumably haven't modified any of the source code between invocations). 
To be clear, normally this will not *run* your program, which is why you don't get a prompt to input any values.

To **run** your program, which, if I understand correctly is what you are trying to do, simply run the executable `deleteme` that was produced by the build process. You will most likely find this executable in the build directory, that is, the directory where you ran the `cmake --build .` command. (Depending on your CMake project structure, you may also find it in a subdirectory of your build directory.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the cmake commands but I am certain about build and run process. I am just using eclipse buttons to build (that hammer) and the green triangle to run. One of the benefits of using an IDE should be to not have to worry about commands. My problem is: the build and run works fine if I put a cout at the beginning but wrongly if I don't put it.  In other words, this code won't run without a cout at the beginning. Sounds crazy, I know, but it's what's happening.

Comment: May I suggest then that you add some detail to your question as well as provide complete output listings of both building and running. As it looks now I'm guessing the output is truncated in some way. Another idea would be to run the commands manually and compare results.